# datagrid not working in angular with asp.net core version 2.2

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I am using Datagrid widget from Devextreme, in asp.net core & angular based project.

JSON response is below.

```
{
    "result": {
        "items": [
            {
                "firstName": "Asu",
                "lastName": "Voh",
                "emailId": "Asu@g.com",
                "dateOfBirth": "2020-12-12T00:00:00",
                "isdiabetes": "No",
                "gender": "Female",
                "isadmittedbefore": false,
                "isDeleted": false,
                "deleterUserId": null,
                "deletionTime": null,
                "lastModificationTime": null,
                "lastModifierUserId": null,
                "creationTime": "2020-12-12T00:00:00",
                "creatorUserId": null,
                "id": 4
            }
        ]
    },
    "targetUrl": null,
    "success": true,
    "error": null,
    "unAuthorizedRequest": false,
    "__abp": true
}
```

Below is angular code I am using, below is html file code.

patient.component.html :

```
<div [class]="containerClass">
            <div class="card card-custom">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <dx-data-grid
                        id="patientgrid"
                        [dataSource]="dataSource"
                        [repaintChangesOnly]="true"
                        [showBorders]="true">

                        <dxo-scrolling mode="virtual"></dxo-scrolling>

                        <dxi-column dataField="firstName" caption="{{'FirstName' | localize}}"></dxi-column>
                        <dxi-column dataField="lastName" caption="{{'LastName' | localize}}"></dxi-column>
                        <dxi-column dataField="emailId" caption="{{'EmailId' | localize}}"></dxi-column>
                        <dxi-column dataField="dateOfBirth" caption="{{'DateOfBirth' | localize}}"></dxi-column>
                        <dxi-column dataField="isdiabetes" caption="{{'Isdiabetes' | localize}}"></dxi-column>
                        <dxi-column dataField="gender" caption="{{'Gender' | localize}}"></dxi-column>
                        <dxi-column dataField="isadmittedbefore" caption="{{'Isadmittedbefore' | localize}}"></dxi-column>
                    </dx-data-grid>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Below is ts file code.

patient.component.ts

```
export class PatientsComponent extends AppComponentBase {

    dataSource: any = {};
    refreshMode : string;

  constructor(
      injector : Injector,
      private _patientService: PatientServiceProxy
    ) {
      super(injector);
      this.getData();
  }

  getData(){
      this.refreshMode = "full";

      /*this._patientService.getPatient("").subscribe(
          result => {
              console.log(result);
          });*/

      //http://localhost:22742/api/services/app/Patient/GetPatient

        this.dataSource = new CustomStore({
            key: "id",
            load: (loadOptions) => {
                return this._patientService.getPatient("").toPromise()
               }
           });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

I searched for this error and found solution to update startup.cs file, so I do like below..but still error is coming.

Also I updated my startup file as below.

```
services.AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
```

So any idea what is wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: What is `CustomStore`? Btw. this does not really seem to be related to the ASP.NET Core backend since, as you say, the data is being properly returned by the server.

Comment: @poke this is based aspnetzero framework and customstore is option by devextreme to create datagrid widget.

Comment: Your JSON response does not seem to match the format that appears to be required [according to the docs](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Data_Binding/Specify_a_Data_Source/Custom_Data_Sources/). The items should be in the `data` property for example.

Comment: Yes..you are right..it is done now..Thanks for guidance..

Answer (score 0):

I got solved this, by making this changes in following part.

```
this.dataSource = new CustomStore({
            key: "id",
            load: (loadOptions) => {
                data => response.data
               }
           });
```